# Java Generics Method header

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Say i have some method header..

```
public static <E> void myMethodName(E[], Comparator<E> comparator).
```

Why would I get a type error when attempting to call:

```
myMethodName(int[], 
    new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare(Integer e1, Integer e2) { return e1 - e2; }
    }
);
```

any ideas?

Comment: Because an `int` isn't an `Integer`. In addition, you *can't use primitives* as a generic type.

Comment: Sensible. So in all cases of generics, I need to wrap primitive arrays?

Comment: So ... *it depends*. Here you'd have to because you inferring the type and using it for an array type and a generic type. It's perfectly legal, however, to have a `Comparator<int[]>`. Yes, arrays are special :) They're objects that *hold* primitives vs. being primitive.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's look at a few things.

- You have a generic method (it's missing a variable though, but I'll overlook that) which requires a generic type.  Java infers, based on the fact that your array is of type `int`, that the method is type bound to `Integer`.
- You have a primitive `int[]`, which you are providing as the first argument.  In the formal signature, it is type bound to `Integer`.

The problem here:  **an `int[]` is *not* equivalent to an `Integer[]`**.  They are two completely different objects (since they're both arrays as opposed to objects that can be autoboxed).

The proper way to avoid the issue is to use an `Integer[]` instead.  The elements that you place *inside* the array will be autoboxed according to the rules of autoboxing and conversion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Although autoboxing can confuse the issue, `int` and `Integer` are not the same type.

Comment: Autoboxing provides a way to bridge between `int` and `Integer` though.  That's it's point.

Comment: That is wicked retarded. If you have an explanation as to why that happens, I'd love to hear.

Answer (score 0):

@user2574476 : you can point `E` to any reference type not primitive type.
    So instead of using int[], you should use Integer[].